# List fragment not disappearing

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity

Based on my code whenever I run my app and click a list item, the intended fragment does appear but the list fragment does not disappear from view (see attached screenshot). What needs to be done in order to remove the list from the user's view?

```
    FragmentItem1 newFragment = new FragmentItem1();
    FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

    transaction.replace(R.id.master_container, newFragment);                         

transaction.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
    transaction.addToBackStack(null);
    transaction.commit();
```

[image]
[image]

**Back button method**

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (mTwoPane) {
        FragmentMainList newFragment = new FragmentMainList();
        FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

        // Replace whatever is in the master_container view with the above fragment
        transaction.replace(R.id.master_container, newFragment);
        transaction.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);

        // Commit the transaction
        transaction.commit();
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: post your code, so to fix bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that 'master_container' is a layout that is adjacent to your ListView, what you are are currently observing is the correct behavior. The ListView won't disappear automatically.

Invoke the **setVisibility** on your ListView to make it disappear. Use the parameter **ListView.GONE** for this method

Comment: Yep, fine but The text doesn't do to the top of the screen so technically the list fragment is still there check latest screenshot.

Comment: The text "This is item 1" doesn't go up after calling View.INVISIBLE ?

Comment: `ListView.GONE` worked so thx for that. However when I click the back button, the list view doesn't reappear. How can I ensure it does?

Comment: I think for the back thing, you can override onBackPressed. First let it call the super method and then add a line to invoke setVisibility again. This time, pass ListView.VISIBLE

Comment: Almost. The only problem I now have is the back button press method as my list is not reappearing. Please check my latest screenshot and back button event code.

Comment: You did not invoke setVisibility in onBackPressed

Comment: I have now but still an error, please check latest screenshot

Comment: Well the error is related to where you have declared list_main. If you just declare it as a class variable and not a method variable, the error should be resolved.